# How To Create The New Areas As Separate Project In .Net Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have tried to create simple .net core 2.0 project using areas in separate projects. There is some articles, but for mvc 5. I have tried to create new .net core 2.0 project different than the main one and make reference ( main project has reference to areas project).

When I start main project and type the url of the main project but with the area name without controller and action, it says 'Ambiguous URLs  between controllers in area project' but after that when I add controller and action it says '404 NOT FOUND'.

The solution tree looks like this:

```
Solution[Directory]
  AreaProject
    Controller
    Models
    Views

  MainProject
    Controller
    Models
    Views
```

I don't want to make two projects and deploy them separately and redirect through urls.